# Searching by multiple values within a redis key/value

Tags: node.js, redis

I was told to use Redis for store authenticated users in my application on Heroku, so I decided to jump in today.  What I want to do is store hashes of users in the Redis store like this:

```
{
   id:4532143215432,
   username:'davejlong',
   email:'dave@davejlong.com'
}
```

And then I want to be able to search by either username or id.  Is this possible with Redis somehow?

I am using the node.js redis module which supports any redis command https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few problems in @orangeoctopus usecae.

> redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET id:4532143215432 username davejlong emaildave@davejlong.com 
>   OK 
>   redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET user:davejlong id 4532143215432 email dave@davejlong.com
>   OK

This will make duplication, think about adding new values and deleting & updating.

So I prefer this

```
SET user:davejlong 1
HMSET user:1 username davejlong email dave@davejlong.com
```

1) In case of username

```
 redis.get('user:davejlong',function(err,id){
     console.log('User Id of @davejlong: ' + id);
     redis.hgetall('user:'+id,function(err,user){
        console.log('User Data: ' + user);
     })
  })
```

2) In case of Id

```
   redis.hgetall('user:1',function(err,user){
       console.log('User Data: ' + user);
    })
```

Comment: I eluded to this with "A more compact way of doing this..." but was too lazy to type it out. +1

Comment: Sorry I missed the point since you are not adding the ability to find by mail.
`SET user:dave@davejlong.com 1`
and you are able to find by mail

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as storing each user twice. Once with the key of id and once with the key of username.

A more compact way of doing this in terms of memory is to have usernames key to ids, so your username query would like like: query by username, get id; put in id, get info.

Unfortunately, there isn't a good way to have the same actual data be keyed on by two different keys.

---

For example, when you would insert a new user and then query for it:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET id:4532143215432 username davejlong email dave@davejlong.com
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET user:davejlong id 4532143215432 email dave@davejlong.com
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HGET id:4532143215432 username
"davejlong"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HGET user:davejlong id
"4532143215432"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMGET user:davejlong email id
1) "dave@davejlong.com"
2) "4532143215432"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> DEL user:davejlong
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> DEL id:4532143215432
(integer) 1
```

Notice that when I am creating the user, I use HMSET twice. Now, I can query against either the username or the id. I also have to delete both keys now.

Comment: Could you show me how I would do that in the CLI?  I'm brand new to all this redis stuff, so I'm not sure whether to use a hash, list, etc.

Comment: You are creating duplicate data here. Consider the use indexes.